# Add another subsection to the RenderFragment with some parameters

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make my own DataGrid component:

Component File: Grid.razor

```
@typeparam TableItem

@using System.Collections.Generic

@if (ItemsList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @HeaderTemplate
                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in ItemsList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @RowTemplate(item)
                        </tr>

                    }
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

}

@code {



    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TableItem> ItemSource { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment HeaderTemplate { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TableItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowSorting { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<TableItem> ItemsList { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ItemsList = ItemSource;
    }

}
```

Page where component is used: test.razor

```
...
 <Grid ItemSource="@MySource">      
        <HeaderTemplate>         
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <RowTemplate>
            <td>@context.Column1</td>
            <td>@context.Column2</td>
            <td>@context.Column3</td>
        </RowTemplate>

    </Grid>
...
```

What I would like to do is to add another 'subsection'to the RenderFragment and expose some paremeters like so: In my test.razor page:

```
<Grid ItemSource="@MySource">      
        <HeaderTemplate> 
            <AnotherSecion Parameter1 =  ..., Parameter2 = ..../>
```

Is this possible? I'm trying to build the table without writing the  and  tags in the parent page.

Thanks.

Comment: You simply can use another component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to build the table without writing the and tags in the parent page

Unlike Html usage of tags, Blazor requires you to provide the opening tags as well as the closing tags. This is needed by the RenderTreeBuilder in order to build the virtual DOM which is the underlying layer used to render the components, and calculate html diffs.

You can, however, add a component that is to be rendered as part of the HeaderTemplate, as for instance, the following component serves as the header of a pet table, displaying the name of the first pet in a list of pets. But of course you can make it more sophisticated, say when a user select a row pet, you change the header to reflect this, etc... :

```
<TableTemplate Items="pets" Context="pet">
    <TableHeader>
        <tr><TableHeaderTitle Name="@pets.First().Name" /></tr>

        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>

    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate>
        <td>@pet.ID</td>
        <td>@pet.Name</td>
    </RowTemplate>
</TableTemplate>

@code{

        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>() { new Pet { ID = 1, Name = "Dog"},
                                          new Pet {ID = 2, Name = "Cat" },
                                          new Pet {ID = 3, Name = "Horse"}};
public class Pet
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And your TableHeaderTitle component may look like this:

```
 <p>Name: @Name</p>

 @code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Note that you can also add a ChildContent property of type RenderFragment if you want to add child content to the component.

Comment: Excellent. Great help.